# Redundant entry of a Fugal Exposition

Tags: theory, harmony, classical-music, analysis, fugue

When analyzing a fugue, I get confused at times about where to put the redundant entry. Is it the 5th or more entry of the subject and/or answer? I’m not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In a 'textbook fugue' it's an (optional, and not ALL that common - so don't worry if you can't find it!) extra occurrence of the subject in the exposition section of a fugue, after all the voices have stated the subject (or countersubject),   So, in a 4-voice fugue it will be the 5th occurrence of the subject.

Not to be confused with anything that happens after the exposition.  And not all fugues are 'textbook'.

Comment: I would modify the above answer to say that one expects an entry in each voice. The redundant one, doesn't necessarily have to be the last sounding, although it is likely to be.